# (C++) I am trying to output the contents in a double array but it's not printing any decimal places when I need them to have a .00 on the end

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, double, cout

[This is my first semester learning C++ so bear with me :) please]

I was able to write the program to work as intended, but without the decimal places that my professor wants in step 3 (seen below)

1. Declare three arrays of double type and initialize them with the following values:

mathScores[] {93, 88, 93, 84, 90}

chemScores[] {77, 92, 84, 76, 82}

avgScores[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

2. Compute the average scores using the for loop:
   avgScores[i] = (mathScores[i] + chemScores[i])/2
3. Print the results on the screen nicely as shown below:

ID math chem average

0 93.00 77.00 85.00

1 88.00 92.00 90.00

. . .

Any ideas to get the decimals to output when I click run because whenever I run the program it just outputs 93, 77, 85, etc. instead of 93.00, 77.00, 85.00, etc. like my professor wants. Also, the setw() is to ensure the outputted values are spaced apart. (code I wrote is seen below)

```
double mathScores[] = {93, 88, 93, 84, 90};
double chemScores[] = {77, 92, 84, 76, 82};
double avgScores[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

cout << "ID" << setw(5) << "Math" << setw(5) << " Chem " << setw(5) << "Average" << endl;

for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    avgScores[i] = (mathScores[i] + chemScores[i])/2;
    cout << i << setw(5) << mathScores[i] << setw(5) << chemScores[i] << setw(6) << avgScores[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: do you have the same issue with `double x = 0.00; std::cout << x;` ? I think this has nothing to do with matrices or arrays.

Comment: If you have difficulty outputting a certain value, the first thing you should do is write a simple 2 line program attempting to output the value.  Computing averages, arrays, etc. is not relevant to the issue you're having.  For example, [start with this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39fa81110e4feb16) and experiment with the manipulators to get the desired result.  If you still can't get the result, post your attempt using *that* program.

Comment: `double z = 0.00; std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << z << "\n";`

Comment: Alright. Thanks everyone for the help. I was completely unaware of "fixed" in the cout statement. I got my solution and learned some new things. Thank you! :)